# Where to find URL of running application in VSCode?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

With new Flutter panel I do not see Dart VM Service url of the running application in the debug console, as before. Where can I find it?

[image]

Comment: try checking the Output Panel and its various channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still shows in the Debug Console, but in your screenshot it's being filtered out. You can click the icon to the right of "Showing 0 of 7" to clear your filter.

[image: filtered debug console]

You can also copy it from the language status area:

[image: Dart language status]

Or using the Copy VM Service URI command in the palette (`F1`):

[image: Copy VM Service URI command]